# How would I have multiple selenium browsers running at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently making a script utilizing selenium. I would like multiple "tasks" to be running at the same time. How would I write code to have the same code running multiple times at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `threading` for this. Here's a short example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading


def go_to_example(driver):
    driver.get('https://example.com')


drivers = []
for _ in range(3):
    drivers.append(
        webdriver.Chrome()
    )
threads = [threading.Thread(target=go_to_example, args=(d,)) for d in drivers]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Thanks for sharing. I've updated the code to be more pythonic.

Comment: Should I make my whole program into a function so it would work with threading?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Generally it's important to encapsulate the implementation to support threading. In this case your selenium functionality might go inside the `go_to_example` function, it doesn't have to be the whole program.

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm getting this error: "TypeError: 'WebDriver' object is not iterable
"

Comment: You are probably iterating over the webdriver element instead of the list of `drivers` somewhere in the code.